# Test-script execution failure in Selenium-IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Error in test-case- EXPECTED: Test case successfully executed. But actual: [error] current test case not found in Selenium IDE.

Comment: You're going to need to add more details and actually ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to put more information on there to get a definite answer. But as a wild guess, if you're seeing this error I'd imagine you're trying to run a test suite, and since the suite was created one of the cases contained in it has been deleted, renamed or moved

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that test case is moved from the exact location. 
To run that test again first delete the test case from selenium IDE.
Then press CTR+D and select the test case file again.
Then try to run.